# Run Ubercart (Drupal Module) in Test Gateway mode without SSL?

Tags: drupal, ubercart

I'm writing a module for Ubercart that hooks the checkout completed phase of purchasing. However I'm running into an issue actually running any tests.

My original plan was to use the Test Gateway for development, then push out this module onto production with Paypal and Google Checkout as payment gateways. Once I get it going I can afford an SSL certificate.

However right now I don't have an SSL certificate, and this is preventing Test Gateway from running since it depends on the Credit Card Module, which *requires* SSL. Surprisingly the debug mode option doesn't change this requirement.

At the top of every page I get an ominous warning:

> Checkout cannot be completed without any payment methods enabled. Please contact an administrator to resolve the issue.

And at the top of the Payment Settings page I get:

> Credit card encryption must be configured to accept credit card payments.

Is there any way to force the Credit Card module to work in debug mode without SSL?

Comment: Where are you seeing that the Credit Card module requires SSL? I've used the Credit Card and Test Gateway on a staging site without SSL and it's worked fine for testing.

Comment: @Matt At the top of every page in the warnings, and at the empty Payment Gateway list. I guess that the Credit Card module see's the site isn't SSL and disables itself

Comment: Hmm... I just double checked my staging site and it has the Credit Card module enabled, Test Gateway enabled, but no SSL configured and no error messages. Have you tried enabling the Test Gateway module?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you enable "Test Gateway", go here http://YOURSITE/admin/store/settings/payment/edit/methods (Administer › Store administration › Configuration › Payment settings)

Expand "Credit card settings", in "Card number encryption key filepath" enter path outside of your site. "
On "Accepted card types" select any credit card. And investigate more settings there.

Now try buy some product, and checkout it, select card for payment, it will automatically complete order (full payment imitation).See [testing numbers](http://www.google.ru/search?q=credit+card+for+testing) for credit cards, CVV can be any number, enter higher Expiration date than current date.

Use sandboxes for testing [Paypal](https://developer.paypal.com/) and [Google Checkout](https://sandbox.google.com) for testing these "gates".

Comment: Ah, I didn't fully understand that option and thought it was only for an actual production website. Thanks for clearing this up and getting it working